# Powershell script can not run when invoke in .NET process

Tags: .net, powershell, process, specflow

I have one question about `Powershell` can not run through inside .NET `Process`.

I have the following Powershell

```
$livingDocPath = "C:\Users\chris\.dotnet\tools\livingdoc.exe"

$dllPath = "C:\Mylib\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\Mylib.dll"

$jsonPath = "C:\Mylib\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\TestExecution.json"

$command = "test-assembly"

$parameter = "-t"

& $livingDocPath $command $dllPath $parameter $jsonPath
```

BTW, `livingdoc` is a dotnet tool, which I confirmed is well installed in my machine.

This script can run through if I run it in the shell directly. The expected behavior is it will produce a html report.

But, when I try to execute this powershell script in a .NET process, it can not generate the expected result:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var binFolder = @"C:\Users\chris\Desktop\powershell";
            var arguments = Path.Combine(binFolder, "testLivingdoc.ps1");
            arguments = "-command " + arguments;
            Console.WriteLine($"script start with argument: {arguments}");

            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"powershell",
                Arguments = arguments,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false
            };

            using var p = Process.Start(startInfo);
            var stdError = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            var stdOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stdError))
                Console.WriteLine($"powershell running error: {stdError}");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stdOutput))
                Console.WriteLine($"powershell running result: {stdOutput}");
        }
```

You can see the `testLivingdoc.ps1` is my script.

I tried a simple script which just prints the version of livingdoc tool,

```
$livingDocPath = "C:\Users\chris\.dotnet\tools\livingdoc.exe"
& $livingDocPath --version
```

Then it can run through inside the .NET process.

So what's happening here?

Comment: Do you get any error output? What is the exit code of the process? (Inspect $LastExitCode in the script immediately after calling `& $livingDocPath ...`)

Comment: no any error message, just the application just hung there.

Comment: BTW, If I on purpose make the path of json file wrong, then I can get the error message complaining "can't find the file".

Comment: Why are you not using the powershell.exe file already installed on the machine? It looks like the .NET process is executing a PowerShell command line installed in your user folder. Are you sure you and the .NET tool are using the same version of PowerShell?